# Guest additions in virtualbox

Tags: 16.10, guest-additions

I am one of those using ubuntu as a guest OS.
Once I am done using the guest additions iso file, can I safely eject it or do I have to put it intact forever?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can eject it after installation is complete.

This can be verified by, for example, rebooting it after ejecting it and then doing something that requires the Guest Additions, like resizing the window and seeing that the size of the desktop changes.

Answer (score 0):

The Guest additions is a drivers disk.  It has support drivers much like a disk with printer drivers, video drivers, network drivers and other hardware specific drivers that are shipped with different computers.

Once the drivers are installed, the disk can be removed.